# How do I append multiple raw inputs to a list using a loop?

Tags: python

Title's pretty explanatory.

Here's where I'm at:

```
itemlist = list()
new_item = raw_input ("Input new item: ")

if new_item == "Done": break
else:
    itemlist.append(new_item)
    print itemlist
    continue
```

I'm fairly new at this so I'm having issues occasionally with placing the "continue" and "break" functions properly, so I keep getting errors with that

As for printing the itemlist, I never ends so I have to manually cancel it (CTRL + C)

I just want it so it'll loop back and ask me to continue inputting new items until I type "Done".

I know it's probably a simple solution.

Comment: you forgot to add a loop ;)

Comment: As the error message (`'break' outside loop`) was telling you...

Answer (score 2):

The idiomatic thing to use in python is `while True:`

```
itemlist = list()
while True:
  new_item = raw_input ("Input new item: ")
  if new_item == 'Done':
    break
  itemlist.append(new_item)
```

Comment: Not a big deal, but you forgot "print itemlist".